# Como popular um p:datatable com uma List<> que contém dois atributos List<> dentro?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, aplicação-web

Passei o dia inteiro hoje tentando fazer uma coisa que supostamente é simples mas não consegui. É o seguinte, estou usando o primefaces e sou nova nisso ainda e preciso de alguma maneira popular minha  `<p:datatable>` com um uma lista de objetos. Até ai ok. Mas dentro do objeto da lista eu tenho mais duas listas. Exemplo:

```
List<GastosMes> gastosAno

public class GastosMes {
   public int mesReferente
   List<Conta> contas
   List<Comida> comidas
} 

public class Conta{
   public Double valorGas;
   public Double valorAgua;
   public Double totalContas;
}

public class Comida{
   public Double valorFeijao;
   public Double valorArroz;
   public Double totalComida;
}
```

Supondo este exemplo bobo, tenho duas listas dentro do objeto GastosMes. A lista GastosMes é então passada para minha página (retornada pelo gastosAnoController.gastosAnoList), mas daí só consigo exibir OU as Contas OU as Comidas. Meu xhtml está assim :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{gastosAnoController.gastosAnoList}"
                var="gastosMes">

                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Mês" style="width:100px" />
                        <p:column colspan="3" headerText="Gastos do Ano Corrente" />
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column headerText="Gastos Contas" />
                        <p:column headerText="Gastos Comida" />
                        <p:column headerText="Total Líquido" />
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>                                        
                <p:subTable var="conta" value="#{gastosMes.contas}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{gastosMes.mesReferente}" />
                    </f:facet>  
                    <p:column>                      
                    </p:column> 
                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputText value="#{contas.valorFeijao}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{contas.valorArroz}" />
                    </p:column>     
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{conta.totalContas}" />
                    </p:column>                     
                </p:subTable>                   
</p:dataTable>
```

como dá pra ver, eu criei uma subtable (pesquisei um monte e só achei ela como "solução") e consegui preencher as colunas com os atributos da lista de Contas. O problema é que preciso preencher a tabela com os atributos da lista de Comida também, como faço ? alguma ideia? tentei colocar duas subtables, duas datatables, nada ficou legal. Se alguém puder me ajudar.

OBS: Como vou separara por mês, achei que seria mais pratico criar a classe GastosMes e dentro dela ter uma lista de contas e comidas relativas a este mês.

Comment: Acho que tem vários componentes que você pode usar para compor o datatable, mas depende do que você quer fazer (pode usar o ui:repeat em vez de da subtable). Por exemplo, veja essa pergunta em que o usuário precisava agrupar uma lista de checkboxes dentro de outra lista de checkboxes. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169839/60946

Answer (score 1):

Quando você criou sua `subTable` você poderia ter usado o valor do `dataTable` como referência, exemplo:

```
<p:subTable var="bean" value="#{gastosMes}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{gastosMes.mesReferente}" />
                    </f:facet>  
                    <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bean.valorGas}" />                     
                    </p:column> 
                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputText value="#{bean.valorFeijao}" />
                    </p:column>                    
                </p:subTable>
```