# Ui:repeat - pegando a descricao no banco

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Olá ..gostaria de saber ,como faço pra organizar o meu ui:repeat...

por que na página,ele exibe : **Mudança de Horario** e o campo do checkbox,
                             **Trabalho Noturno** e o campo do checkbox

resumindo eu queria poder organizar ele ...o código ele pega de uma lista ,e que estas descrições estão inseridas na tabela descrição no banco de dados,ex:mudança de horário e etc...

como faço pra exibir na página organizado,tipo quantas mensagens eu quero na horizontal,quantas na vertical ..pq o dataTable já fiz o teste e não pega

Quero deixar alguns na vertical e horizontal, e colocar o campo do checkbox primeiro,segue como exibe na minha página 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<ui:repeat  value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.listaQuestoes}"  var="questao">
                                <p:outputLabel  value="#{questao.descricao}"  for="questao"/>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="questao"/>
                            </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom... Não sei se entendi corretamente sua dificuldade, mas tentei fazer uma simulação. Acho que colocar checkboxes na horizontal e vertical conforme sua necessidade fica meio difícil sem usar um datatable. Creio que a solução esteja na entidade `Questão` (se eu entendi corretamente seu problema). Veja como ficou o modelo abaixo:

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{controlador.listaQuestoes}" var="q" styleClass="width: 40%;">
    <p:column headerText="Ativa">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="questao" value="#{q.ativa}">
            <p:ajax />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descrição">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{q.descricao}"  for="questao"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Questões Relacionadas">
        <c:if test="#{not q.relacionadas.isEmpty()}">
            <ui:repeat value="#{q.relacionadas}" var="r">
                <h:panelGroup style="padding: 10px;">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="relacionda" value="#{r.ativa}">
                        <p:ajax />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{r.descricao}" for="relacionda"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:repeat>
        </c:if>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

No Bean:

```
private List<Questao> listaQuestoes = new ArrayList<Questao>();

public List<Questao> getListaQuestoes() {
    if (this.listaQuestoes.isEmpty()) {
        this.inicializarQuestoes();
    }
    return this.listaQuestoes;
}

public void setListaQuestoes(List<Questao> listaQuestoes) {

    this.listaQuestoes = listaQuestoes;
}

public void inicializarQuestoes() {
    Questao q = null;
    this.listaQuestoes.clear();
    q = new Questao("Mudança de horário");
    q.getRelacionadas().add(new Questao("Horário Integral"));
    q.getRelacionadas().add(new Questao("Horário Parcial"));
    this.listaQuestoes.add(q);
    q = new Questao("Trabalho noturno");
    this.listaQuestoes.add(q);
    q = new Questao("Trabalho em horário extraordinário");
    this.listaQuestoes.add(q);
    q = new Questao("Desconto em salário");
    q.getRelacionadas().add(new Questao("Desconto X"));
    q.getRelacionadas().add(new Questao("Desconto Y"));
    q.getRelacionadas().add(new Questao("Desconto Z"));
    this.listaQuestoes.add(q);
}
```

Entity Questao:

```
public class Questao {

    private String descricao;

    private boolean ativa;

    private List<Questao> relacionadas = new ArrayList<Questao>();

    public Questao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.ativa = false;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {

        return this.descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {

        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public boolean isAtiva() {

        return this.ativa;
    }

    public void setAtiva(boolean ativa) {

        this.ativa = ativa;
    }

    public List<Questao> getRelacionadas() {

        return this.relacionadas;
    }

    public void setRelacionadas(List<Questao> relacionadas) {

        this.relacionadas = relacionadas;
    }

}
```

Comment: era desse mesmo jeito Marcus.. tinha pesquisado e realmente com o dataTable funcionaria.Obriigado ! –

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu resolver. Caso a resposta tenha ajudado, ficarei grato se sinalizar como resolvido, pois ajuda nos pontos. Obrigado.